# Invalid GeoJSON object, converted from ArcGIS JSON

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I queried some ArcGIS JSON from "Global Forest Watch API", then converted it to GeoJSON using a web service.

When I try to add it to my Leaflet map I get "Invalid geojson object".

The GeoJSON looks like this:

```
 {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
              43.36960659625765,
              -22.252918060115043
            ],
            [
              43.3694190980949,
              -22.25288200352778
            ],
            [
              43.36917877180695,
              -22.252807617249033
            ],
            [
              43.36895751944741,
              -22.25271034218535
            ],
            [
              48.97787106415192,
              -16.582301013579393
            ],
            [
              48.977741977143914,
              -16.582301013579393
            ],
            [
              48.97748380402619,
              -16.582301013579393
            ],
            [
              48.97722563001018,
              -16.58217192710138
                ]
              ]
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "OBJECTID": 1974,
            "CLASS": "IFL2016",
            "AREA_HA": 58083.0137401,
            "CLASS_NAME": "IFL2016",
            "AREA": 580830137.401,
            "GlobalID": "{94379FB6-6962-498B-A9DC-30FEC0EE1D49}",
            "Shape_Length": 360660.35501490464,
            "Shape_Area": 633182785.1308166
          },
          "id": 6
        }
      ]
    }
```

NOTE - the list of coordinate is much longer, I only included 2 for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test GeoJSON here: http://geojsonlint.com/

In this case, it says:

> Line 9: a LinearRing of coordinates needs to have four or more
>   positions
>
> Line 9: the first and last positions in a LinearRing of coordinates
>   must be the same

If your orginal JSON contains more coordinate pairs, please include at least 4, including the last one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ran the entire geoJSON through that site and had no problems. Unsure why I cannot display it in leaflet.

Comment: Edit - I solved the problem, thanks.